# Eigenvalue problem for ordinary differential equation

Tags: ode, eigenvalues, scipy

I am trying to compute the natural frequency of a cantilevered beam.
The Euler-Bernoulli equation reduces to the following problem :
$$
v''''=\lambda v, \text{with  }, v(0)=0, v'(0)=0, v'''(1)=0,v''(1)=0
$$

where superscript $'$ correspond to  derivation.
These are the steps to obtain a solution:

1. reduce the problem to a system of first order differential equation

$$
v'=v_1\\
v_1'=v_2\\
v_2'=v_3\\
v_3'=\lambda v
$$
with the boundary conditions
$$
v(0)=0\\
v_1(0)=0\\
v_2(1)=0\\
v_3(1)=0
$$
2) write the system in python (`k`correspond to $\lambda$)

```
def fun(x, y):
    return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3], k*y[0]))
def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0], ya[1],yb[2],yb[3]])
```

3. define grid and initial conditions

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

y_0 = np.zeros((4, x.size))
y_0[0]=np.sinh(x)
y_0[1]=np.cosh(x)
y_0[2]=-np.sinh(x)
y_0[3]=-np.cosh(x)
```

4. at this point my idea, I use `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`  to solve the boundary value problem varying the parameter $k$:

```
k_list=[1.80,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.84,1.85]    
for k in k_list:    
    soly= solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_b)
    print(soly.status)
    y_plot = soly.sol(x)[0]
    plt.plot(x, y_plot, label='y_b')
```

And take as the right eigenvalue the value for which `soly.sol` is equal to $0$, but, for the previous code, I obtain a solution for all the value in `k_list`.

Even if I implement a shooting method, which is the right method to check to see if I got the right eigenvalue ?

Comment: A good way to solve your problem is discretize the equation on a spatial grid and convert it to linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @MaximUmansky, you are, probably, better using a discretization method such as (see this [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/37090/9667)):

- [The Finite Difference Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method);
- [The Finite Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method); or
- [The Ritz method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritz_method).

Finite differences are really simple to understand as discretization technique but the boundary conditions get messy really fast, particularly for your higher order case.

I would suggest to go with the Finite Element Method. If you insist in using the shooting method, you could check [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35091/9667).